# Removing a point feature that seems protected against removal

Tags: qgis, kml, gps-track-editor

What if changes to a certain dataset are protected?

Can't remove a faulty point in the regular way. The dataset is created by myself in the field. A set of GPS locations imported as a KML file. One is just offline the transect.

Comment: How is the file protected?  What have you tried with respected to editing the data in QGIS.  Please edit the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit kml files in QGIS, al least it's not possible to delete features. Convert (export) your kml-file in a Geopackage or ShapeFile. Alternatively, you could edit the kml-file in Google Earth or in a text-editor.
See also here: [Edit KML with the mouse in QGIS: is it possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84133/edit-kml-with-the-mouse-in-qgis-is-it-possible)