# See and edit the contents of a KML file within QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml

When I open a KML file in VS Code or vim I see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="2963760840" id="2963760840">
    <SimpleField name="timestamp" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="begin" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="end" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="altitudeMode" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="tessellate" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="extrude" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="visibility" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="drawOrder" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="icon" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>2963760840</name>
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#2963760840">
        <SimpleData name="tessellate">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibility">-1</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
    <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605 -88.431737410907,31.6559161822374 -88.4317340478576,31.6559522520483 -88.4317304294607,31.65598830298 -88.4317265546618,31.6560243350402 -88.4317224234424,31.6560603464253 -88.4317180368385,31.656096335324 -88.4317133937868,31.6561323008421 -88.4317084963772,31.6561682411606 -88.4317033435555,31.6562041562871 -88.4316979352941,31.6562400435163 -88.4316922726381,31.6562759019385 -88.4316863545151,31.6563117297579 -88.4316801819788,31.6563475269666 -88.4316737560565,31.6563832908516 -88.4316670756934,31.6564190214205 -88.4316601419166,31.6564547159601 -88.4316529536625,31.6564903735763 -88.4316455130305,31.6565259933519 -88.431637818957,31.6565615743927 -88.4316298724689,31.6565971139855 -88.431621673566,31.6566326121303 -88.4316132232843,31.6566680670158 -88.4316045205513,31.6567034768459 -88.4315955664119,31.6567388407112 -88.431586360857,31.6567741577097 -88.4315817286416,31.6567915607419 -88.4311466897599,31.6584809674529 -88.4311356263598,31.658529215528 -88.431124815372,31.6585775059521 -88.431114256788,31.6586258378234 -88.4311039516355,31.658674208429 -88.4310938999238,31.6587226186706 -88.4310841005811,31.6587710667524 -88.431074554662,31.6588195526667 -88.4310652631943,31.6588680737005 -88.4310562240697,31.6589166298692 -88.4310474404426,31.6589652202479 -88.4310389101867,31.6590138430485 -88.4310306343658,31.6590624991651 -88.4310226129532,31.6591111858924 -88.4310148459404,31.6591599023285 -88.4310073343821,31.6592086484659 -88.4310000772153,31.6592574234104 -88.4309930754678,31.6593062244489 -88.430986329149,31.6593550524834 -88.4309798382413,31.6594039057101 -88.4309736027451,31.6594527841292 -88.4309720419662,31.6594653415 -88.4309644366008,31.6595394733955 -88.4309570876343,31.6596136241626 -88.4309499950584,31.6596877928994 -88.4309431588736,31.659761979606 -88.4309365790716,31.6598361833805 -88.4309302545895,31.6599104033289 -88.4309241875368,31.6599846394358 -88.4309183768417,31.6600588899053 -88.4309128225048,31.6601331547375 -88.4309075245268,31.6602074339324 -88.4309024839445,31.6602817256786 -88.4308976996953,31.6603560290821 -88.4308931717888,31.6604303450447 -88.4308889012709,31.660504672657 -88.43088488707,31.6605790101229 -88.4308831265363,31.6606132013205 -88.430880160709,31.6606753008115 -88.4308774511835,31.6607374083529 -88.4308749990237,31.6607995248388 -88.4308728042029,31.6608616475637 -88.4308708656675,31.6609237765354 -88.4308691844632,31.6609859108443 -88.4308677605907,31.6610480504906 -88.4308665929691,31.6611101927763 -88.4308656826711,31.6611723394975 -88.4308650296705,31.6612344879487 -88.430864901764,31.6612506351474 -88.4326782034786,31.6612204116202 -88.432897502907,31.6542440681409 -88.4317454858576,31.6541186481987 -88.4317646239949,31.6548099837846 -88.431765521614,31.65484436124 -88.4317663085529,31.6548787413071 -88.4317669858568,31.6549131230762 -88.4317675535255,31.6549475065475 -88.4322256604991,31.6549477172071 -88.4321986103415,31.6558080866836 -88.4317459607727,31.6558078776201 -88.4317433668281,31.6558439941254 -88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

Is it possible to see or edit a KML file within QGIS?

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84133/edit-kml-with-the-mouse-in-qgis-is-it-possible help?